# php - Comparing associative and numeric array using array_diff

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

Array1 is an associative array containing multiple lists fetched from MySQL, and Array2 is a numerical array, i.e a simple array. Array2 has list_ids, which are to be used to filter the Array1.

Sample of Array1:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => 1
        [list_id] => 68
        [list_value] => List-68
        [subject] => "abc"
        [message] => "abc"
        [obj_var] => "abc"
        [url_link] => "abc"
        [list_time] => 2014-05-13 22:04:04
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [id] => 2
        [list_id] => 69
        [list_value] => List-69
        [subject] => "abc"
        [message] => "abc"
        [obj_var] => "abc"
        [url_link] => "abc"
        [list_time] => 2014-05-13 22:04:04
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [id] => 3
        [list_id] => 80
        [list_value] => List-80
        [subject] => "abc"
        [message] => "abc"
        [obj_var] => "abc"
        [url_link] => "abc"
        [list_time] => 2014-05-13 22:04:04
    )
    [3] => Array (
        [id] => 4
        [list_id] => 81
        [list_value] => List-81
        [subject] => "abc"
        [message] => "abc"
        [obj_var] => "abc"
        [url_link] => "abc"
        [list_time] => 2014-05-13 22:04:04
    )
)
```

Array2:

`[68, 81]`

My output should be:

```
Array (     
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => 2
        [list_id] => 69
        [list_value] => List-69
        [subject] => "abc"
        [message] => "abc"
        [obj_var] => "abc"
        [url_link] => "abc"
        [list_time] => 2014-05-13 22:04:04
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [id] => 3
        [list_id] => 80
        [list_value] => List-80
        [subject] => "abc"
        [message] => "abc"
        [obj_var] => "abc"
        [url_link] => "abc"
        [list_time] => 2014-05-13 22:04:04
    )
)
```

So, under normal circumstances `array_diff()` would do it, but here it won't work. I tried converting the numerical Array2 into an associative and used `array_diff_assoc()` function, but still didn't work.

I also tried iterating through my numerical array and check each element in the associative Array1 (i.e each fetched row from MySQL) for each number in the numerical array.

```
foreach ($list as $val) {
    while ( $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo $val."<br/>";
        if($r['list_id'] != $val ) {
                $new[] = $r;
        }
    }       
}
print_r($new);
```

But the output echoes only the first number of numerical Array1 4 times (the length of Array1) and hence only one `list_id` is removed out of the associative Array2 instead of 2:

```
68
68
68
68
Array (     
    [0] => Array (
        [id] => 2
        [list_id] => 69
        [list_value] => List-69
        [subject] => "abc"
        [message] => "abc"
        [obj_var] => "abc"
        [url_link] => "abc"
        [list_time] => 2014-05-13 22:04:04
    )
    [1] => Array (
        [id] => 3
        [list_id] => 80
        [list_value] => List-80
        [subject] => "abc"
        [message] => "abc"
        [obj_var] => "abc"
        [url_link] => "abc"
        [list_time] => 2014-05-13 22:04:04
    )
    [2] => Array (
        [id] => 4
        [list_id] => 81
        [list_value] => List-81
        [subject] => "abc"
        [message] => "abc"
        [obj_var] => "abc"
        [url_link] => "abc"
        [list_time] => 2014-05-13 22:04:04
    )

)
```

So, how can I make it work? What would be the optimum algorithm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `foreach` loop with `in_array` check to `unset` unwanted elements :

```
foreach ($Array1 as $key => $value)
    if(in_array($valeu['list_id'], $Array2)) unset($list[$key]);
```

Comment: Alright, this worked. I couldn't `mysqli_fetch_all` cause the associative array didn't contain `list_id` as the key for each list's ID. So right now, before looping through this foreach loop, I have to loop through my result and add the rows to `$Array1`.

Answer (score 1):

I've simplified your code to the following.

```
$arr1 = array();
while ( $r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) { $arr1[] = $r; }
$arr2 = array(68,81);

// the magic happends here. It will return an array with only the elements that matches the id of those values in $arr2
$filtered = array_filter($arr1, function ($val) use ($arr2) { return !in_array($val['id'], $arr2); });
```

Comment: I **do not** want to return elements where there is a match. Sorry if my question wasn't clear, but I meant I want elements which did not match in both the arrays.

Comment: well that's easy, just put a !, I changed the answer for you

Comment: Okay that looks good now. Also, any optimum way to avoid the `while` loop? Because that is adding up another loop. `mysqli_fetch_all` should let me add all my rows to `$arr1` but then the key for each id is an index (incrementing numbers) instead of `list_id`.

Comment: As long as that while loop has no queries or other heavy tasks, it is absolutely no problem to use it like that. The way I put it in the answer is probably the most performant you can do it. The mysqli_fetch_all internally does something similar.